# Boost::asio::streambuf consume() doesn't empty the buffer

Tags: c++, boost

I have following implementation of a function reading serialized data.

The only problem is that buffer to which the data is written doesn't seem to overwrite the data. 
Instead after each function call, buffer appends new data.

I read about `consume()` which I belive would make it work, but calling it doesn't empty the buffer.

Code below:

```
void Client::read_msg() {
    boost::asio::async_read_until(socket, stream_buf, "\n", [this](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::istream is(&stream_buf);
            std::getline(is, read_msg_string);
            ss << read_msg_string;
            cereal::BinaryInputArchive iarchive(ss);
            iarchive(txt);
            std::cerr << txt.header << " " << txt.body;
            stream_buf.consume(stream_buf.size());
            this->read_msg();
        } else {
            socket.close();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: think you might need a commit() in there, before consume.

Comment: Tried it before, doesn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

A few ideas:

1. Reading a binary archive with a single `getline` is definitely a bad idea (you would never read past a byte having `0x0a` (linefeed)).
2. close streams/archives before modifying the underlying buffers/streams
3. use the transferred size or keep buffer_size from before the read operations (I don't think this should matter, but it's one variable to eliminate)

So, for a start there would be

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << &stream_buf;
{
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive iarchive(ss);
    iarchive(txt);
    std::cerr << txt.header << " " << txt.body;
}
```

But I think it could just be

```
{
    std::istream is(&stream_buf);
    cereal::BinaryInputArchive iarchive(is);
    iarchive(txt);
    std::cerr << txt.header << " " << txt.body;
}
```

As far as I know, the `streambuf` operations shown will already call `consume()` as required.

If you expect trailing data to be present, you probably will not want to consume it, but rather close the socket (if  you blindly ignore trailing data, the conversation partner will end up confused about what you have received)